# Exception :unrecognized selector sent to instance Dismissing View Controller in IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have open another view successfully in current view using the following code

```
 OptionsViewController *optionView = [[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"OptionsViewController_ipad":@"OptionsViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:optionView animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

They i'm trying to dismiss current view in  `OptionsViewController` using the following code. But im getting `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` and app crashes in IOS 8 but lower version it was working fine . Please help me how to resolve .

Please check below link for exception message http://pastebin.com/R4M3MxmM

```
- (IBAction)cancelOption:(id)sender
    {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a copy of the actual message rather than a description of it.  It helps to know which instance and which selector.

Comment: @PhillipMills   please check below link http://pastebin.com/R4M3MxmM

Answer (score 0):

The trace says your problem is in `[LeftSideBarViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]`.  Apparently, you're asking for the `count` of something but that thing is currently a `UITraitCollection` which, I'm guessing, is not what you expect.

The most likely explanation is that the thing you're trying to count has been released and its memory reused.

If it's not obvious from that, run Instruments with zombies enabled and look at the retain/release history of the object involved.  (Or post the code from the crashing method.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i didnt call LeftSideBarViewController when i close view (OptionsViewController)  controller.  thats what i count not find

Comment: I have no idea what you called, but look at the stack trace.  The line that causes the error says: 5   wepa                                0x000deea4 -[LeftSideBarViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] + 68.  I don't know enough about your app to have made up that class name.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**:count** on the object doesn't exist.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitSet_ClassReference/index.html

UITraitCollection has no instance method called **count**.